# Redirect rule that keeps connection mode (HTTPS | HTTP) in Lighttpd

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, config, lighttpd

I have a redirect rule so every request will be forced to have `www.` before them, the problem is that if someone connects through `https://` they are redirect to `http://` because I don't know what command should I use to difference between them. THis is the rule:

```
var.mdomain = "mydomain.com"
var.mdomainregexredir = "^mydomain\.com$"

$HTTP["host"] =~ var.mdomainregexredir {
  server_name = var.mdomain 
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://www." + var.mdomain + "/$1" )
}
```

If possible, I want to know if there's a way to use only one redirect rule, I mean, I don't like to add 2 `url.redirect`, one inside `http` and another inside `https`, I want it to be like this (Simplified):

```
url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => (isHttps?"https":"http") + "://www." + var.mdomain + "/$1" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need is this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ var.mdomainregexredir {
    $HTTP["scheme"] =~ ".*" { # catch http and https
        # %0 references the above matched pattern (http or https)
        # also changed to just catch the whole path and redirect using it with $0
        url.redirect = ( ".*" => "%0://www.varmdomain$0" )
    }
}
```

Unless you have a compelling reason, I'd be redirecting everything to https. You can do the https and www redirects all as one too.

Comment: Oh, `$HTTP["scheme"]`. Perfect! Thank you! The reason I want to do this is because the web is a Facebook canvas site. When an user uses the secure Facebook, they will use my https site, and when they don't want to, they won't use my https site. If they decided not to use https when navigating on Facebook, I don't want to force them to because my site is integrated in Facebook.